# Правильно ли расставлены знаки? Тире нужно?

Tags: пунктуация

Сразу сказать, что лучше выбрать из этих средств – Супрастин или Фенистил, нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать проще и обособить запятыми:

Что лучше выбрать из этих средств, **супрастин или фенистил**, сразу сказать нельзя.

Употребление прописных букв желательно уточнить, например:  [http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=названия%20лекар](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80)

Answer (score 0):

Сразу сказать, что лучше выбрать из этих средств – Супрастин или Фенистил, – нельзя. Запятая закрывает сложное предложение, а тире выделяет вставную конструкцию: **Супрастин или Фенистил.**

Comment: Закрывает сложное? А не придаточное разве?

Comment: А придаточное - не сложное?

Comment: Просто мне кажется, что "закрывать предложение" можно в самом его конце, но я не разбираюсь, как в этом контексте говорят, поэтому лишь предположил, что так надо сказать.

Comment: Артем, в этом предложении в придаточном находится вставня конструкция, которая выделяется при помощи парного тире, а запятая закрывает придаточное предложение.

Comment: Да я понял! Я сам, когда прочитал вопрос, так и подумал, что надо закрыть вставную конструкцию тире, а запятую оставить. Но я не спец в вопросах, когда остаются оба знака, а когда тире поглощает запятую, поэтому не был уверен. У вас: *а запятая закрывает **придаточное** предложение* в комментарии — именно так я предложил написать в самом ответе. ;)